# JUnit. Netbeans. Ant

Tags: junit

This image was a test and runned from Netbeans. i was perfect. it runned all my 17 tests.

Then when i runned it in using ant, it only runned 1 test and 1 error.

Test run : 1 Failures:0 Errors:1 Skipped:0 Time elapsed:0sec

MY junit test code.

```
<target name="junit" depends="compile">
  <junit printsummary="yes">
      <test name="${test.class.name}" />
         <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
  </junit>
</target>
```

HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `test` test runs a single test. You can use `batchtest` to run multiple tests:

```
<target name="junit" depends="compile">
    <junit printsummary="yes">
        <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
        <batchtest>
            <fileset dir="${test-dir}" includes="**/Test*.class" />
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

Comment: junit:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\dzeyy\Downloads\Project\ProgAppsLabPrelimsProj\ProgAppsLabPrelimsProj\b
uild.xml:94: junit doesn't support the nested "batchset" element.

Total time: 1 second

Comment: But when     <target name="junit" depends="compile">
    <junit printsummary="yes">
        <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
  
    </junit>
</target> It does not do anything.          junit:

Comment: @JayDeGuzman that's a typo on my behalf - it should be `batchtest`. Edited and fixed - try it now

Comment: BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\dzeyy\Downloads\Project\ProgAppsLabPrelimsProj\ProgAppsLabPrelimsProj\b
uild.xml:94: C:\Users\dzeyy\Downloads\Project\ProgAppsLabPrelimsProj\ProgAppsLab
PrelimsProj\${test-dir} does not exist.

Comment: @JayDeGuzman that was a placeholder. You need to supply the directory that holds your tests, of course.

Comment: <target name="junit" depends="compile">
    <junit printsummary="yes">
        <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
        <batchtest>
            <fileset dir="${tests.dir}" includes="**/Test*.java" />
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target> And the output was. empty again :(

Comment: Why does it output empty?

Comment: junit:
    [junit] Testsuite: SolutionTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 se
c
    [junit]
    [junit] Null Test:  Caused an ERROR
    [junit] SolutionTest
    [junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SolutionTest
    [junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    [junit]
    [junit]
    [junit] Test SolutionTest FAILED

Comment: <target name="junit" depends="compile">
  <junit>
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="bin" />    
      <pathelement location="lib/junit-4.12.jar"/>
    </classpath>    
    <batchtest>
       <fileset dir="${test.dir}">
            <include name="**/*Test*" />
       </fileset>
    </batchtest>
    <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>
  </junit>
</target>

Comment: When i run the test on NetBeans. The results : Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0,  And that is my expected output,